# "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer" error when declaring a function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool compare(int a[3], int b[3]) {
    for (int i=2; i>=0; i--) {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) {
            return a[i] > b[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int arr[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}};

    sort(arr, arr+3, compare);
}
```

I'm making a program for a competitive programming question where I have to sort an arrays of arrays:

- the arrays should be sorted based on the last integer
- if the last integer is the same, sort them based on the second integer (and so on)

When I ran this program, I got 5 errors:

```
[{
    "resource": "/c:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 1822,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 1822,
    "endColumn": 17
},{
    "resource": "/c:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "invalid array assignment",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 1824,
    "startColumn": 24,
    "endLineNumber": 1824,
    "endColumn": 24
},{
    "resource": "/c:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_heap.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 262,
    "startColumn": 18,
    "endLineNumber": 262,
    "endColumn": 18
},{
    "resource": "/c:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_heap.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "invalid array assignment",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 263,
    "startColumn": 17,
    "endLineNumber": 263,
    "endColumn": 17
},{
    "resource": "/c:/msys64/ucrt64/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_heap.h",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 355,
    "startColumn": 22,
    "endLineNumber": 355,
    "endColumn": 22
}]
```

I've looked up several other questions on Stack Overflow regarding the same error but I can't find one that is similar to my exact issue. I'll use structs in the meantime, but I want to know what's wrong with this code specifically.

Comment: `std::sort` likely can't sort plain arrays (as in, a container with plain arrays as elements). Switch to `std::array` elements.

Comment: [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Comment: Unrelated: If you need to use arrays, use `std::array` instead of c-style arrays.

Comment: For `std::sort` to work it has to be able to copy elements of the container it is sorting. In your case the container is `int[3][3]` so the elements of that container are `int[3]`. Now here's the thing. in C++ **arrays are not copyable**. So this approach cannot work. As already said use `std::array` instead, `std::array` is copyable.

Comment: Note that, as a function parameter, `int a[3]` actually means `int* a`. The array-like syntax is just a hint for the human reader that the argument is supposed to be a pointer to an array element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "C" style array, use std::array and you will get compares for free.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

// using namespace std; <== unlearn to use this

int main() 
{
    std::array<std::array<int,3>,3> values{{{1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}}};
    std::sort(values.begin(),values.end()); // learn to use .begin() and .end() too
}
```